# custom datagridviewcolumnheadercell height

Tags: c#, vb.net, datagridview, header, custom-controls

So far: I managed to combine some code that works and shows a standard datagridview with standard column with standard height of headercell. If I set up columnheadercell height in datagridview properties the height gets accepted as usually.

Goal: I'd like to implement default columnheader height of a standard datagridviewtextboxcolumn inside of my own custom datagridview called 'datagridview_filter'. I'd like to set custom columnheader height permanently for my new datagridview. I'm close but...

This creates my custom DGV:

```
Public Class DataGridView_Filter

End Class
```

with underlying .designer file:

```
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()>
Partial Class DataGridView_Filter
Inherits System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView

'Control overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()> _
Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
    Try
        If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
            components.Dispose()
        End If
    Finally
        MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
    End Try
End Sub

'Required by the Control Designer
Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

' NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Component Designer
' It can be modified using the Component Designer.  Do not modify it
' using the code editor.
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> _
Private Sub InitializeComponent()
components = New System.ComponentModel.Container()
End Sub

End Class
```

And I created a new custom datagridviewcolumncell called 'datagridviewcolumncell_filter':

```
Public Class DataGridViewTextBoxColumn_Filter

Public Sub New()

    Me.CellTemplate = New DataGridViewCell_Filter()
    Me.ReadOnly = True

End Sub

End Class
```

with an underlying .designer file:

```
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()>
Partial Class DataGridViewTextBoxColumn_Filter
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn

    'Control overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()> _
    Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
    Try
        If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
            components.Dispose()
        End If
    Finally
        MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
    End Try
End Sub

'Required by the Control Designer
Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

' NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Component Designer
' It can be modified using the Component Designer.  Do not modify it
' using the code editor.
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> _
Private Sub InitializeComponent()
    components = New System.ComponentModel.Container()
End Sub
```

End Class

and a custom datagridviewcell called 'datagridviewcell_filter':

```
Public Class DataGridViewCell_Filter

    Inherits DataGridViewTextBoxCell

End Class
```

with an underlying .designer fie:

```
    Partial Class DataGridViewCell_Filter
      Inherits System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxCell
```

'Control overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
  <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()>
  Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
      Try
          If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
              components.Dispose()
          End If
      Finally
          MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
      End Try
  End Sub

  'Required by the Control Designer
  Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

  ' NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Component Designer
  ' It can be modified using the Component Designer.  Do not modify it
  ' using the code editor.
  <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()>
  Private Sub InitializeComponent()
      components = New System.ComponentModel.Container()
  End Sub

End Class

> **EDIT:**
>    I stumbled upon 'datagridview_filter[design]' mode and I noticed that I can change properties of 'Datagridview_filter' when in [design] mode. Imagine my happy face right that moment. One can set up anything there. Everything gets saved for future reference. But... when I insert 'Datagridview_filter' into blank Form all settings go away as if they were never there. So I get columnheaderheight 18 instead of 40 saved in custom 'datagridview_filter[design]' properties. So it seems I'm in the same place as I was before.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the solution. It was actually quite simple. Here's the example with header set to 60.

```
Public Class DataGridView_Filter

Inherits DataGridView

Private Sub DataGridView_Filter_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint

    Me.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.EnableResizing
    Me.ColumnHeadersHeight = 60
    Me.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.DisableResizing

End Sub

End Class
```

So after a lot of time and earning a **'TUMBLEWEED'** badge I finally found this solution. The best thing about it ... it's totally customized datagridview and can be used directly from toolbox.